# Object not getting From Datasnapshot using valueEventListerner but Working find but AddChildEventListern

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When i try to get a Object from addChildListerner(DataSnapShot) it works fine and assign to DataSnapshot to object

This working fine:

```
  myRef = database.getReference("Chat").child(Combine);
    myRef.orderByKey().limitToLast(1).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            ChatData user = dataSnapshot.getValue(ChatData.class);
            userChild.add(user);
```

But when i try to get same Object using ValueListerner(snapshot) app crash
i have use everything `snapshot.getChildern ()`  `snapshot.getValue` then app crash.

Error With

```
myRef = database.getReference("Chat").child(Combine);
myRef.orderByKey().limitToLast(1).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        ChatData user = dataSnapshot.getValue(ChatData.class);
                        userChild.add(user);

                }
```

i want to retrieve 
 ChatData user = dataSnapshot.getValue(ChatData.class);
                  userChild.add(user);

```
Debug time : 

         DataSnapshot { key = 
                     1123469ACDEFFFFGJKLNOOOPQSTUUVWZabccdehhkkloopqruuuuwxyy, 
                     value
                           = {-LrjsM3ZO0pzQbvCcRuQ
                           ={time=Tue Oct 22 00:53:10 GMT+05:00 2019
                           , msg=hi
                            , user_ID=LuFro93OCcPEpoFTKuQhUkeuw462}} 
                              }
```

How to get this Value

[image: Database Image]

Comment: what do you want to retrieve?

Comment: Question Updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

In your first example, the Firebase client handles the list, and calls your `onChildAdded` for each result. But with a `ValueEventListener`, you get a single snapshot with all results. So your `onDataChange` will need to handle this list, which you do by iterating over the `DataSnapshot.getChildren()`.

Something like this:

```
myRef.orderByKey().limitToLast(1).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            ChatData user = userSnapshot.getValue(ChatData.class);
            userChild.add(user);
        }
    }
```